# Is there a windows 7 shortcut key to dock to the top of screen?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a widescreen monitor at work that I have rotated 90 degrees - effectively making it a "longscreen" monitor. I find the long profile much more useful for code.

I know I can use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to move a window to the left or right half of the screen respectively, similarly <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> will maximise or minimise.

The question is, are there a similar key combinations to move a window to the top or bottom half of the screen for when I am using the "longscreen" monitor?

edit: Since its a work controlled machine, it is hard to get software installed so a native solution would be best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aero snap doesn't support half/half horizontally which is what you are doing with the keys. You can however arrange two windows horizontally if they are in the same program by shift-right-clicking on the program group if two or more windows are open and then stack horizontally.

Comment: Hmmm... I was mostly going to be having different PuTTY windows stacked on the longscreen so this is pretty handy. Although it does mean I need to combine taskbar items, which is a drag.

Comment: This is the only way in windows 7 without getting a custom window manager which exist.