# Any shortcut to resize a window to half top/bottom of screen?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, window

In Windows 10, is there any keyboard shortcut to resize a window to half top/bottom of screen?

There is a tool (https://maxto.net/)  for this, but I wonder if there is a built-in shortcut for this specific requirement or not.

Comment: Related: [Possible to “snap” top/bottom instead of just left/right in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/285356/150988)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to "snap" top/bottom instead of just left/right in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/285356/possible-to-snap-top-bottom-instead-of-just-left-right-in-windows-7)

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate, but it matched my Google search query better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a few apps that do this.

- [AquaSnap](https://www.nurgo-software.com/products/aquasnap): Free for personal use.
- [WinSnap](https://www.ntwind.com/software/windowspace.html): Has a "free download" button right next to a "purchase lifetime license" button, so the "free download" is probably just a trial license.
- [MaxTo](https://maxto.net/en) (formerly WinSplit Revolution): Not free.
- [DisplayFusion Pro](https://www.displayfusion.com/)
- [NVIDIA nView](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/design-visualization/solutions/nview-display/): pretty buggy (at least on Windows 10), but this is what I eventually settled on.  Lets you partition your display any way you want.

Comment: AquaSnap is only free for a single-screen setup and nView is only compatible with some computers/graphics cards. The others are paid software

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately there are no shortcuts for that.
The closest method I found is to use `win + left + up` and `win + left + down` 
to have the windows in the top and bottom left quarters. It is important to press left before pressing up/down, otherwise the window will maximize/minimize before docking.

Then you have to resize manually each of the window's width.

Answer (score 7):

There is also a [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) from Microsoft. I.e. you don't need to trust a third-party developer and it's free.
It has a feature called FancyZones where you can divide your monitors into zones(grid) and have the windows snap to that grid that you have configured.

Comment: FancyZones is what I ended up settling on when I was looking for a Windows equivalent to spectacle on OSX.  It has built-in presets for rows and columns, so a top/bottom split is straight-forward.  It can optionally replace the win+left_arrow/right_arrow keyboard shortcuts.  Also can't beat free.

Comment: It is an amazing software I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

To resize Chrome windows, there's also the [Window Resizer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh) extension